# DataSelect causes error DataSelect takes 3 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create a webdatabase.

So far so good. I have an issue however I'm trinyg to select the UserID in my dataname from a table tbl_login

I'm getting an error No overload for method dataSelect takes 3 arguments.
Here is the code.
This code is in my Class1.cs

```
public DataTable DataSelect(string query)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = query;
                DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
                DataAdapter1.Fill(dt);
                DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection.Close();
                ErrorMessage = "";

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                ErrorMessage = err.Message;
                DataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection.Close();               
            }

            return dt;

        }
```

This code is in my default.aspx.cs

```
        DataLayer.DataConnector dat = new DataLayer.DataConnector("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= '" + Server.MapPath("MainData.accdb") + "'; Persist Security Info=false");
```

Hope someone is able to assist me

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing obviously wrong with the DataSelect method itself, aside from that it takes 1 argument, not 3 (hence the compiler error). Could you please post the line of code where the method is called?